# Scroll UItextfield when keyboard shows up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, keyboard, uitextfield

I have a `UIView` which is added as an subview to `UIScrollView` the `UIView` contains `UITextField` and `UITextView`in order to avoid the keyboard hiding the fields I have registered for `keyboardWasShown` and `keyboardWillHide` notifications and I have this piece of code written

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    isKeyboardUp = YES;

    // Step 1: Get the size of the keyboard.
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    // Step 2: Adjust the bottom content inset of your scroll view by the keyboard height.
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height, 0.0);
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    CGRect TextFieldFrame;
    if(activeTextField)
    {
        TextFieldFrame = [activeTextField.superview convertRect:activeTextField.frame toView:self.view];
    }
    else
    {
        TextFieldFrame = [activeTextView.superview convertRect:activeTextView.frame toView:self.view];
    }

   [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:TextFieldFrame animated:YES];
}

- (void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    isKeyboardUp = NO;
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

Here `activeTextField` and `activeTextView` are current use text field this works good in most of the cases but fails in few can someone suggest if there is anything wrong with the implementation.

Comment: use this https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: I do not intend to use any third party framework.

Comment: Have you set delegate to all the UITextFields.

Comment: Yes I have done that carefully

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are using scrollview then you can simplty use `TPKEYBOARDTYPING`
 It is available on cocoa pods or you can get it from github it self.
add its files then simply go to your storyboard and in scrollview change its class to tpkeyboardtypingscrollview.

It will give all neccessary things like Resign keyboard on return and will change the offset of scrollView itself so that your textFields will not be hide behind your Keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

**try this one**

```
-(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification {

NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
keyboardHeight = kbSize.height;
[self updateScrollViewPosition];
}

 -(void)keyboardDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {

NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
CGSize kbSizeBegin = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
CGSize kbSizeEnd = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
if (kbSizeBegin.height != kbSizeEnd.height) {
    keyboardHeight = kbSizeEnd.height;
    if (activeTextField && [activeTextField isFirstResponder]) {
        [self updateScrollViewPosition];
    }
}
}

-(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)notification {

keyboardHeight = 0;
activeTextField = nil;
[self resignAllTextFields];
} 

#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate Methods

 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
activeTextField = textField;
return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

activeTextField = textField;
[self updateScrollViewPosition];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

keyboardHeight = 0;
activeTextField = nil;
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
 }

#pragma mark - Update Method

-(void)updateScrollViewPosition {

if (keyboardHeight > 0 && activeTextField) {
    CGRect frame = activeTextField.frame;
    CGFloat yPoint = scrollView.frame.origin.y+frame.origin.y+frame.size.height+8.0;
    CGFloat height = self.view.frame.size.height-keyboardHeight;
    CGFloat diff = yPoint-height;
    if (diff > 0.0) {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, diff) animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        CGFloat diff = scrollView.contentSize.height-scrollView.contentOffset.y;
        if (diff<scrollView.frame.size.height) {
            diff = scrollView.contentSize.height-scrollView.frame.size.height;
            if (diff < 0) {
                diff = 0.0;
            }
            [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, diff) animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
else {
    CGFloat diff = scrollView.contentSize.height-scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    if (diff<scrollView.frame.si  ze.height) {
        diff = scrollView.contentSize.height-scrollView.frame.size.height;
        if (diff < 0) {
            diff = 0.0;
        }
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, diff) animated:YES];
    }
}
 }
```

**to resign**

```
-(void)resignAllTextFields {

for (UIView *view in containerView.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField*)view;
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
[self updateScrollViewPosition];
}
```